# RTSP to HTT using VLC command line

Tags: video, vlc, javascript, html5, rtsp

I have a camera which gives output in form of RTSP. However we want to run it on a browser inside HTML tag. For which we need HTTP url using terminal. I saw few posts which uses cvlc but I was not able to get the correct output. Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: Web-browsers do not support just raw RTP (RTSP). You will need someting like WebRTC to get it going. Or you can re-package to HLS or DASH as a second option (this will have more latency however).

Comment: @DimitriPodborski Yea, I googled and got a WebRTC server i.e antmedia. It produced the frame link in HTML that I can play in HTML. Thanks alot.